# R assign value dynamically to element of data frame

Tags: r

I need to write a line of R that can reference an element of a list using a dynamically generated name.

For example, if I have the list:

```
x <- list(a = "Foo", b = "Bar", c = "Salad")
```

And a variable

```
v1 <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"),1)
```

I need to be able to change an element of that list using something like

```
x$v1 <- "Something else"
```

This last line, of course, does not work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: use the `x[[v1]] <- "Something else"` instead of `$`

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in the comment above:

use the `x[[v1]] <- "Something else"` instead of `$` – akrun